# Casting model to dynamic, setting new property and returning as camelCased json

Tags: c#, .net, casting

I have an object of some model class. For one of my endpoints(of multiple) I need to attach to this object additional property and then return all as camelCased JSON. My issue is having something like this:

```
public class MyObject {
    public string Property1{get;set;}
    public string Property2{get;set;}
}
```

```
public IActionResult ReturnWithAdditionalProperty(MyObject myObject) {

    var dynamizedObject = (dynamic)myObject;
    dynamizedObject.NewProperty = true;
    return Json(dynamizedObject)
}
```

fails on setting NewProperty (model is still shown as MyObject item).

As I don't want to add it to model (this property is used only in one case) or create new model (i.a. due to large number of properties), I would like just to make it dynamic with new property, then return.

How can I do it? Currently I'm making Json serialization and deserialization as dynamic, but this unfortunately ends with returning PascalCase variable names instead of camelCase.

One more note: I need it for endpoint potentially returning large list of such elements - it should be possibly fast.

Answer (score 0):

I found some solution, but I'm not sure if this is the best one:

```
 public static class ExpandoConvert {

    public static ExpandoObject ConvertToExpando(object obj) {
        var expando = new ExpandoObject();
        var dictionary = (IDictionary<string, object>)expando;

        foreach (var property in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
            dictionary.Add(property.Name, property.GetValue(obj));

        return expando;
    }
}
```

and using this:

```
 public IActionResult ReturnWithAdditionalProperty(MyObject myObject) {
 
     var dynamizedObject = ExpandoConvert.ConvertToExpando(myObject);
     dynamizedObject.NewProperty = true;
     var jsonSerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings {
            ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver(),
            Formatting = Formatting.Indented
        };

     return Json(query, jsonSerializerSettings);
 }
```